# Change App.RootVisual

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a Main Project that will load other projects with MEF according to the "Role" of the actor who did the Login, for example :

if username is "project1" i will load the project1 and its correspondent XAP, Models,ViewModels and Views.

So i'll need to change my App.RootVisual and set the MainPage according to the current project.

I've been looking for solutions on internet and found almost the same things done by different ways and i've tried this:

First i set my RootVisual as a Grid on Application_Startup:

```
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        this.RootVisual = grid;
        grid.Children.Add(new MainPage());
```

So after my Authentication methods return me what project i must load i do this :

```
            var grid = App.Current.RootVisual as Grid;
            grid.Children.RemoveAt(0);
            grid.Children.Add(new Project1MainPage());
```

I created a ContentControl on my MainPage that is binded to a DependencyProperty :

```
            <ContentControl Name="region1ContentControl" Content="{Binding Path=MainContent}" Style="{StaticResource ContentControlStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,30" />
```

This ContentControl is where i Load all my Views, so i have this in all my Project's MainPages and they are all binded to a Dp named MainContent like shown above.

So when i change my RootVisual to a new ProjectMainPage it works fine, but when i try to load a view on my ContentControl i get this :[image]

With the following InnerException:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Element is already the child of another element.
em MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
em MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property,        DependencyObject doh)
em MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property,   Object obj)
em System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
em System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
em System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
em System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(DependencyProperty dp)
em System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget()
em System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourcePropertyChanged(PropertyPathListener sender, PropertyPathChangedEventArgs args)
em System.Windows.PropertyPathListener.ReconnectPath()
em System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingBreakPoint.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BreakOnSharedType>b__3()}
```

and StackTrace :

```
   em System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   em System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   em System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   em System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   em MainPagexaml_9.BindingOperation(Object BindingState, Int32 , Action )
```

Anyone knows what i can do or another solution to change UI ??
Hope i was clear on my question,Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for a navigation frame and/or Prism Modules.

Prism Option - If every "role" in your project is a Prism module, you can load them in a Module catalog and show them as necessary based on the role:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430868(v=pandp.40).aspx

Navigation Frame option - If you use a Navigation frame from the System.Windows.Controls.Navigation namespace as the container on your MainPage you can set up a UriMapper and redirect the contents of the frame to each Role page as necessary.

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx